# Test my Android app on my smartphone - step by step

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm learning how to code Android apps and I'd like to use my smartphone (Samsung Galaxy) for testing and debugging my app as I build it..

I tried to Google a complete tutorial, one that takes you from the very first step, up until the last step where all you got left to do is to click the green Play button on eclipse, but my search came up with nothing.. All I could find were tutorials that started somewhere in the middle of the process.

If there is someone here which is experienced enough in Android development, and willing to scribble a simple step by step tutorial, me and thousands of newbies like me worldwide will thank you!!!

OK, so I have eclipse running on the computer in front of me, my smartphone in one hand and a USB cable on the other, now what?

Comment: This question is too broad to be a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STEP 1: First of all for your project to run it must be free of errors

STEP 2: If you are planning to test the app in real device then you must first ready it

```
    Go to Settings-> Developer Options -> Enable the Developer Options
    Then you must enable "USB Debugging"
```

Step 3: Run your project. It is necessary that your phone is connected in USB Debugging mode via USB cable.

Step 4: In the dialog under "choose a running android device" select your phone model and run

[image]

Step 5: Monitor "Logcat" for any errors.

NOTE : Your are running your application in "Debug Mode". If you are planning to release it in playstore you have to convert it to "Release Mode"

Answer (score 0):

What I did, by reading all of above answers and it worked as well: 7 deadly steps

1. **Connect** your **android phone** with the pc on which you are running **eclipse/your map project.**
2. Let it install all the necessary **drivers.**. When done, open your smart phone, go to: **Settings > Applications > Development > USB debugging** and enable it on by clicking on the check button at the right side.
3. Also, enable **Settings > Unknowresoures**
4. Come back to **eclipse** on your pc. Right click on the project/application, **Run As > Run configurations... >Choose Device>Target Select your device Run.**
5. Click on the **Target** tab from top. By default it is on the first tab **Android**
6. Choose the second radio button which says **Launch on all compatible deivces/AVDs**. Then click **Apply** at the bottom and afterwards, click **Run**.
7. Here you go, it will automatically install your application's **.apk** file into your smart phone and make it run over it., just like on emulator.

To top it all, see the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXojre_lOag)